# Controlling a Rheostat, having 3 output levels, from the power source

Tags: microcontroller, resistors

Is it possible to create a small, "button" type rheostat, no larger than the circumference of a .25¢ piece, less than 1/8" thick, having 3 output levels of 30v, 60v & 120v, and max input is 120v a/c, with the added ability to change the rheostats output by rapidly switching the power source on and off... e.g., power source flipped on, output from rheostat is 30v, power source flipped on then off, then on again... output from rheostat now 60v, power source switched on/off, on/off, then on, power output at rheostat now at 120v

Comment: What are you really trying to make? You seem to have an idea and have decided that a rheostat is the solution but without any any apparent knowledge of what they are. Explain the problem you are trying to solve with some context and then ask a specific question.

Comment: You are describing a toggle function with a sequencer logic controlled servo motor that moves a dial to pre-calibrated positions.  It seems to be a single purpose rather complicated operation.  You are assuming your requirements for power needs a rheostat.... rather than stating. It's a good idea to outline specs for Inputs, Outputs (V,I) and functions and define scope ( budget, skill, etc)

Answer (score 1):

No.

[image]

*Figure 1. A rotary rheostat.*

Rheostats are variable resistors. They do not give "output levels" of various voltages - although they may form part of a circuit that does.

You seem to be looking for a variable voltage power supply but have not specified any power or current rating.